# How do i implement high-chart graph with android kotlin using volley to populate the graph

Tags: highcharts, kotlin-android-extensions

I have been trying to implement high-chart graph with Andriod volley using kotlin I have succeeded in displaying the graph but using hardcoded data, but now I have been trying to using data from my API using volley.

I have implemented the graph already but using hardcoded data.

---

```
    package com.nasdng.nasdmobileapp

    import android.app.ProgressDialog
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Toast
    import com.android.volley.Request
    import com.android.volley.Response
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
    import com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIChartsClasses.*
    import com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIColor
    import com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIGradient
    import com.highsoft.highcharts.Common.HIStop
    import com.highsoft.highcharts.Core.HIChartView
    import com.shashank.sony.fancytoastlib.FancyToast
    import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.internal.Symbol

    import java.util.ArrayList
    import java.util.Arrays
    import java.util.Collections
    import java.util.HashMap
    import java.util.LinkedList
    import java.util.List
    import java.util.Map

    class TestGraphyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_graphy)

            val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...")
            progressDialog.show()
            val Symbol=intent.getStringExtra("Symbol")

             val chartView = findViewById(R.id.hc)
            val options = HIOptions()

            val chart = HIChart()
            chart.zoomType = "x"
            options.chart = chart

            val title = HITitle()
            title.text = "$Symbol Price"
            options.title = title

            val subtitle = HISubtitle()
            subtitle.text = "Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in"
            options.subtitle = subtitle

            val xaxis = HIXAxis()
            xaxis.type = "datetime"
            options.xAxis = ArrayList(listOf(xaxis))

            val yaxis = HIYAxis()
            yaxis.title = HITitle()
            yaxis.title.text = "$Symbol Price rate"
            options.yAxis = ArrayList(listOf(yaxis))

            val legend = HILegend()
            legend.enabled = false
            options.legend = legend

            val plotoptions = HIPlotOptions()
            plotoptions.area = HIArea()
            val stops = LinkedList()
            stops.add(HIStop(0f, HIColor.initWithRGB(0, 0, 0)))
            stops.add(HIStop(1f, HIColor.initWithRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.0)))
            plotoptions.area.fillColor = HIColor.initWithLinearGradient(HIGradient(), stops)
            plotoptions.area.marker = HIMarker()
            plotoptions.area.marker.radius = 2
            plotoptions.area.lineWidth = 1
            val state = HIStates()
            state.hover = HIHover()
            state.hover.lineWidth = 1
            plotoptions.area.states = state
            options.plotOptions = plotoptions

            val area = HIArea()
            area.name = "USD to EUR"

            var areaData = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(1370131200000L, 0.7695),
                arrayOf(1370217600000L, 0.7648),
                arrayOf(1370304000000L, 0.7645),
                arrayOf(1370390400000L, 0.7638),
                arrayOf(1370476800000L, 0.7549),
                arrayOf(1370563200000L, 0.7562),
                arrayOf(1370736000000L, 0.7574),
                arrayOf(1370822400000L, 0.7543),
                arrayOf(1370908800000L, 0.751),
                arrayOf(1370995200000L, 0.7498),
                arrayOf(1371081600000L, 0.7477),
                arrayOf(1371168000000L, 0.7492),
                arrayOf(1371340800000L, 0.7487),
                arrayOf(1371427200000L, 0.748),
                arrayOf(1371513600000L, 0.7466),
                arrayOf(1371600000000L, 0.7521),
                arrayOf(1371686400000L, 0.7564),
                arrayOf(1371772800000L, 0.7621),
                arrayOf(1371945600000L, 0.763),
                arrayOf(1372032000000L, 0.7623),
                arrayOf(1372118400000L, 0.7644),
                arrayOf(1372204800000L, 0.7685),
                arrayOf(1372291200000L, 0.7671),
                arrayOf(1372377600000L, 0.7687),
                arrayOf(1372550400000L, 0.7687),
                arrayOf(1372636800000L, 0.7654),
                arrayOf(1372723200000L, 0.7705),
                arrayOf(1372809600000L, 0.7687),
                arrayOf(1372896000000L, 0.7744),
                arrayOf(1372982400000L, 0.7793),
                arrayOf(1373155200000L, 0.7804),
                arrayOf(1373241600000L, 0.777),
                arrayOf(1373328000000L, 0.7824),
                arrayOf(1373414400000L, 0.7705),
                arrayOf(1373500800000L, 0.7635),
                arrayOf(1373587200000L, 0.7652),
                arrayOf(1373760000000L, 0.7656),
                arrayOf(1373846400000L, 0.7655),
                arrayOf(1373932800000L, 0.7598),
                arrayOf(1374019200000L, 0.7619),
                arrayOf(1374105600000L, 0.7628),
                arrayOf(1374192000000L, 0.7609),
                arrayOf(1374364800000L, 0.7599),
                arrayOf(1374451200000L, 0.7584),
                arrayOf(1374537600000L, 0.7562),
                arrayOf(1374624000000L, 0.7575),
                arrayOf(1374710400000L, 0.7531),
                arrayOf(1374796800000L, 0.753),
                arrayOf(1374969600000L, 0.7526),
                arrayOf(1375056000000L, 0.754),
                arrayOf(1375142400000L, 0.754),
                arrayOf(1375228800000L, 0.7518),
                arrayOf(1375315200000L, 0.7571),
                arrayOf(1375401600000L, 0.7529),
                arrayOf(1375574400000L, 0.7532),
                arrayOf(1375660800000L, 0.7542),
                arrayOf(1375747200000L, 0.7515),
                arrayOf(1375833600000L, 0.7498),
                arrayOf(1375920000000L, 0.7473),
                arrayOf(1376006400000L, 0.7494),
                arrayOf(1376179200000L, 0.7497),
                arrayOf(1376265600000L, 0.7519),
                arrayOf(1376352000000L, 0.754),
                arrayOf(1376438400000L, 0.7543),
                arrayOf(1376524800000L, 0.7492),
                arrayOf(1376611200000L, 0.7502),
                arrayOf(1376784000000L, 0.7503),
                arrayOf(1376870400000L, 0.7499),
                arrayOf(1376956800000L, 0.7453),
                arrayOf(1377043200000L, 0.7487),
                arrayOf(1377129600000L, 0.7487),
                arrayOf(1377216000000L, 0.7472),
                arrayOf(1377388800000L, 0.7471),
                arrayOf(1377475200000L, 0.748),
                arrayOf(1377561600000L, 0.7467),
                arrayOf(1377648000000L, 0.7497),
                arrayOf(1377734400000L, 0.7552),
                arrayOf(1377820800000L, 0.7562),
                arrayOf(1377993600000L, 0.7572),
                arrayOf(1378080000000L, 0.7581),
                arrayOf(1378166400000L, 0.7593),
                arrayOf(1378252800000L, 0.7571),
                arrayOf(1378339200000L, 0.7622),
                arrayOf(1378425600000L, 0.7588),
                arrayOf(1378598400000L, 0.7591),
                arrayOf(1378684800000L, 0.7544),
                arrayOf(1378771200000L, 0.7537),
                arrayOf(1378857600000L, 0.7512),
                arrayOf(1378944000000L, 0.7519),
                arrayOf(1379030400000L, 0.7522),
                arrayOf(1379203200000L, 0.7486),
                arrayOf(1379289600000L, 0.75),
                arrayOf(1379376000000L, 0.7486),
                arrayOf(1379462400000L, 0.7396),
                arrayOf(1379548800000L, 0.7391),
                arrayOf(1379635200000L, 0.7394),
                arrayOf(1379808000000L, 0.7389),
                arrayOf(1379894400000L, 0.7411),
                arrayOf(1379980800000L, 0.7422),
                arrayOf(1380067200000L, 0.7393),
                arrayOf(1380153600000L, 0.7413),
                arrayOf(1380240000000L, 0.7396),
                arrayOf(1380412800000L, 0.741),
                arrayOf(1380499200000L, 0.7393),
                arrayOf(1380585600000L, 0.7393),
                arrayOf(1380672000000L, 0.7365),
                arrayOf(1380758400000L, 0.7343),
                arrayOf(1380844800000L, 0.7376),
                arrayOf(1381017600000L, 0.737),
                arrayOf(1381104000000L, 0.7362),
                arrayOf(1381190400000L, 0.7368),
                arrayOf(1381276800000L, 0.7393),
                arrayOf(1381363200000L, 0.7397),
                arrayOf(1381449600000L, 0.7385),
                arrayOf(1381622400000L, 0.7377),
                arrayOf(1381708800000L, 0.7374),
                arrayOf(1381795200000L, 0.7395),
                arrayOf(1381881600000L, 0.7389),
                arrayOf(1381968000000L, 0.7312),
                arrayOf(1382054400000L, 0.7307),
                arrayOf(1382227200000L, 0.7309),
                arrayOf(1382313600000L, 0.7308),
                arrayOf(1382400000000L, 0.7256),
                arrayOf(1382486400000L, 0.7258),
                arrayOf(1382572800000L, 0.7247),
                arrayOf(1382659200000L, 0.7244),
                arrayOf(1382832000000L, 0.7244),
                arrayOf(1382918400000L, 0.7255),
                arrayOf(1383004800000L, 0.7275),
                arrayOf(1383091200000L, 0.728),
                arrayOf(1383177600000L, 0.7361),
                arrayOf(1383264000000L, 0.7415),
                arrayOf(1383436800000L, 0.7411),
                arrayOf(1383523200000L, 0.7399),
                arrayOf(1383609600000L, 0.7421),
                arrayOf(1383696000000L, 0.74),
                arrayOf(1383782400000L, 0.7452),
                arrayOf(1383868800000L, 0.7479),
                arrayOf(1384041600000L, 0.7492),
                arrayOf(1384128000000L, 0.746),
                arrayOf(1384214400000L, 0.7442),
                arrayOf(1384300800000L, 0.7415),
                arrayOf(1384387200000L, 0.7429),
                arrayOf(1384473600000L, 0.741),
                arrayOf(1384646400000L, 0.7417),
                arrayOf(1384732800000L, 0.7405),
                arrayOf(1384819200000L, 0.7386),
                arrayOf(1384905600000L, 0.7441),
                arrayOf(1384992000000L, 0.7418),
                arrayOf(1385078400000L, 0.7376),
                arrayOf(1385251200000L, 0.7379),
                arrayOf(1385337600000L, 0.7399),
                arrayOf(1385424000000L, 0.7369),
                arrayOf(1385510400000L, 0.7365),
                arrayOf(1385596800000L, 0.735),
                arrayOf(1385683200000L, 0.7358),
                arrayOf(1385856000000L, 0.7362),
                arrayOf(1385942400000L, 0.7385),
                arrayOf(1386028800000L, 0.7359),
                arrayOf(1386115200000L, 0.7357),
                arrayOf(1386201600000L, 0.7317),
                arrayOf(1386288000000L, 0.7297),
                arrayOf(1386460800000L, 0.7296),
                arrayOf(1386547200000L, 0.7279),
                arrayOf(1386633600000L, 0.7267),
                arrayOf(1386720000000L, 0.7254),
                arrayOf(1386806400000L, 0.727),
                arrayOf(1386892800000L, 0.7276),
                arrayOf(1387065600000L, 0.7278),
                arrayOf(1387152000000L, 0.7267),
                arrayOf(1387238400000L, 0.7263),
                arrayOf(1387324800000L, 0.7307),
                arrayOf(1387411200000L, 0.7319),
                arrayOf(1387497600000L, 0.7315),
                arrayOf(1387670400000L, 0.7311),
                arrayOf(1387756800000L, 0.7301),
                arrayOf(1387843200000L, 0.7308),
                arrayOf(1387929600000L, 0.731),
                arrayOf(1388016000000L, 0.7304),
                arrayOf(1388102400000L, 0.7277),
                arrayOf(1388275200000L, 0.7272),
                arrayOf(1388361600000L, 0.7244),
                arrayOf(1388448000000L, 0.7275),
                arrayOf(1388534400000L, 0.7271),
                arrayOf(1388620800000L, 0.7314),
                arrayOf(1388707200000L, 0.7359),
                arrayOf(1388880000000L, 0.7355),
                arrayOf(1388966400000L, 0.7338),
                arrayOf(1389052800000L, 0.7345),
                arrayOf(1389139200000L, 0.7366),
                arrayOf(1389225600000L, 0.7349),
                arrayOf(1389312000000L, 0.7316),
                arrayOf(1389484800000L, 0.7315),
                arrayOf(1389571200000L, 0.7315),
                arrayOf(1389657600000L, 0.731),
                arrayOf(1389744000000L, 0.735),
                arrayOf(1389830400000L, 0.7341),
                arrayOf(1389916800000L, 0.7385),
                arrayOf(1390089600000L, 0.7392),
                arrayOf(1390176000000L, 0.7379),
                arrayOf(1390262400000L, 0.7373),
                arrayOf(1390348800000L, 0.7381),
                arrayOf(1390435200000L, 0.7301),
                arrayOf(1390521600000L, 0.7311),
                arrayOf(1390694400000L, 0.7306),
                arrayOf(1390780800000L, 0.7314),
                arrayOf(1390867200000L, 0.7316),
                arrayOf(1390953600000L, 0.7319),
                arrayOf(1391040000000L, 0.7377),
                arrayOf(1391126400000L, 0.7415),
                arrayOf(1391299200000L, 0.7414),
                arrayOf(1391385600000L, 0.7393),
                arrayOf(1391472000000L, 0.7397),
                arrayOf(1391558400000L, 0.7389),
                arrayOf(1391644800000L, 0.7358),
                arrayOf(1391731200000L, 0.7334),
                arrayOf(1391904000000L, 0.7343),
                arrayOf(1391990400000L, 0.7328),
                arrayOf(1392076800000L, 0.7332),
                arrayOf(1392163200000L, 0.7356),
                arrayOf(1392249600000L, 0.7309),
                arrayOf(1392336000000L, 0.7304),
                arrayOf(1392508800000L, 0.73),
                arrayOf(1392595200000L, 0.7295),
                arrayOf(1392681600000L, 0.7268),
                arrayOf(1392768000000L, 0.7281),
                arrayOf(1392854400000L, 0.7289),
                arrayOf(1392940800000L, 0.7278),
                arrayOf(1393113600000L, 0.728),
                arrayOf(1393200000000L, 0.728),
                arrayOf(1393286400000L, 0.7275),
                arrayOf(1393372800000L, 0.7306),
                arrayOf(1393459200000L, 0.7295),
                arrayOf(1393545600000L, 0.7245),
                arrayOf(1393718400000L, 0.7259),
                arrayOf(1393804800000L, 0.728),
                arrayOf(1393891200000L, 0.7276),
                arrayOf(1393977600000L, 0.7282),
                arrayOf(1394064000000L, 0.7215),
                arrayOf(1394150400000L, 0.7206),
                arrayOf(1394323200000L, 0.7206),
                arrayOf(1394409600000L, 0.7207),
                arrayOf(1394496000000L, 0.7216),
                arrayOf(1394582400000L, 0.7192),
                arrayOf(1394668800000L, 0.721),
                arrayOf(1394755200000L, 0.7187),
                arrayOf(1394928000000L, 0.7188),
                arrayOf(1395014400000L, 0.7183),
                arrayOf(1395100800000L, 0.7177),
                arrayOf(1395187200000L, 0.7229),
                arrayOf(1395273600000L, 0.7258),
                arrayOf(1395360000000L, 0.7249),
                arrayOf(1395532800000L, 0.7247),
                arrayOf(1395619200000L, 0.7226),
                arrayOf(1395705600000L, 0.7232),
                arrayOf(1395792000000L, 0.7255),
                arrayOf(1395878400000L, 0.7278),
                arrayOf(1395964800000L, 0.7271),
                arrayOf(1396137600000L, 0.7272),
                arrayOf(1396224000000L, 0.7261),
                arrayOf(1396310400000L, 0.725),
                arrayOf(1396396800000L, 0.7264),
                arrayOf(1396483200000L, 0.7289),
                arrayOf(1396569600000L, 0.7298),
                arrayOf(1396742400000L, 0.7298),
                arrayOf(1396828800000L, 0.7278),
                arrayOf(1396915200000L, 0.7248),
                arrayOf(1397001600000L, 0.7218),
                arrayOf(1397088000000L, 0.72),
                arrayOf(1397174400000L, 0.7202),
                arrayOf(1397347200000L, 0.7222),
                arrayOf(1397433600000L, 0.7236),
                arrayOf(1397520000000L, 0.7239),
                arrayOf(1397606400000L, 0.7238),
                arrayOf(1397692800000L, 0.7238),
                arrayOf(1397779200000L, 0.7238),
                arrayOf(1397952000000L, 0.7239),
                arrayOf(1398038400000L, 0.725),
                arrayOf(1398124800000L, 0.7244),
                arrayOf(1398211200000L, 0.7238),
                arrayOf(1398297600000L, 0.7229),
                arrayOf(1398384000000L, 0.7229),
                arrayOf(1398556800000L, 0.7226),
                arrayOf(1398643200000L, 0.722),
                arrayOf(1398729600000L, 0.724),
                arrayOf(1398816000000L, 0.7211),
                arrayOf(1398902400000L, 0.721),
                arrayOf(1398988800000L, 0.7209),
                arrayOf(1399161600000L, 0.7209),
                arrayOf(1399248000000L, 0.7207),
                arrayOf(1399334400000L, 0.718),
                arrayOf(1399420800000L, 0.7188),
                arrayOf(1399507200000L, 0.7225),
                arrayOf(1399593600000L, 0.7268),
                arrayOf(1399766400000L, 0.7267),
                arrayOf(1399852800000L, 0.7269),
                arrayOf(1399939200000L, 0.7297),
                arrayOf(1400025600000L, 0.7291),
                arrayOf(1400112000000L, 0.7294),
                arrayOf(1400198400000L, 0.7302),
                arrayOf(1400371200000L, 0.7298),
                arrayOf(1400457600000L, 0.7295),
                arrayOf(1400544000000L, 0.7298),
                arrayOf(1400630400000L, 0.7307),
                arrayOf(1400716800000L, 0.7323),
                arrayOf(1400803200000L, 0.7335),
                arrayOf(1400976000000L, 0.7338),
                arrayOf(1401062400000L, 0.7329),
                arrayOf(1401148800000L, 0.7335)

            )
            area.data = ArrayList(Arrays.asList(*areaData))

            options.setSeries(ArrayList(listOf(area)))
            chartView.setOptions(options)
            progressDialog.dismiss()





            FancyToast.makeText(this@TestGraphyActivity, Symbol, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.INFO, false).show()

            var priceListUrl = "https://companies.nasdep.com/backup/api/price_list_graph?symbol=SDACORN"
            priceListUrl = priceListUrl.replace(" ", "%20")
            val requestQPriceList = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@TestGraphyActivity)
            val jsonARPrice = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET , priceListUrl , null , Response.Listener { response ->




               for(priceJoIndex in 0.until(response.length())){

                   // any time I try implementing in this loop I get an error

               }



            }, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                FancyToast.makeText(this@TestGraphyActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            })

            requestQPriceList.add(jsonARPrice)

















        }
    }
```

I would like to implement this using Andriod volley

Comment: Hi @Bigfash45, Do you use the official Highcharts Android wrapper? https://www.highcharts.com/blog/products/android/

Comment: Yes I did, I used the time series zoomable and it worked perfectly with their data but I need to use a dynamic data using volley

Comment: Bigfash45 - You need to first load options without data and then in volley callback function add data to the chart.

Comment: how do I go about this I'm kind of a newbie with Andriod

Comment: Bigfash45 - I'm not an Androind expert either, but in the place where you have the comment you should put `chartView.setSeries()`. Please remember that you need to serialize the response first so that it looks the same as in the `areaData` variable.